# Angular list reference not getting updated on item deletion

Tags: javascript, html, angular, list, typescript

I am implementing a feature which displays the selected items from a hierarchy structure, on the right.

slice.component.ts :

```
 import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
    import * as API from '../../shared/api-routes';
    import { DataService } from '../../shared/service/data.service';
    import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

    import html from './slice.component.html';
    import css from './slice.component.css';

    @Component({
      selector: 'slice-component',
      template: html,
      providers: [DataService],
      styles: [css],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })

    export class SliceComponent {
      selections: TreeNode<string>[] = [];
      newList: TreeNode<string>[];

      constructor(dataService:DataService, cd:ChangeDetectorRef) {
        super(dataService, cd);
      }

      public onSliceChange(event:TreeNode<string>):void {
        if(event.selected) {
          this.selections.push(event);
        }
        else {
          var index = this.selections.indexOf(event);
          if(index > -1) {
            this.selections.splice(index, 1);
          }
        }
        this.newList = this.selections.slice();
      }

    }
```

slice.component.html :

```
<p>Slices</p>
<mat-input-container>
  <input #searchInput matInput placeholder="Search for Slices">
</mat-input-container>
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="SliceCheck" *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
  <fortune-select
     (sliceSelected)="onSliceChange($event)">
  </fortune-select>
</div>
<div class="sendToRight">
    <rightside-component
      [sliceTreeNode]="newList">
    </rightside-component>
</div>
</div>
```

rightside.component.ts :

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from '../../shared/dto/TreeNode';

import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent {
  @Input() sliceTreeNode: TreeNode<string>[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  getSlices() : TreeNode<string>[] {
    if (typeof(this.sliceTreeNode) == "undefined" || (this.sliceTreeNode) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.sliceTreeNode;
  }

  deselect(item: TreeNode<string>): void {
    if((item.children) !== null) {
      item.children.forEach(element => {
        this.deselect(element);
      });
    }
    var index = this.sliceTreeNode.indexOf(item);
    if(index > -1) {
      this.sliceTreeNode.splice(index, 1);
    }
    item.selected = false;
  }

}
```

rightside.component.html :

```
  <ul class="selection-list" >
    <li *ngFor="let item of getSlices()">
      <button class="btn" (click)="deselect(item)" *ngIf="item.selected">
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item.displayName }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
  </ul>
```

In my implementation, everything works as expected until the following happens :

You delete an item from the rightside list, it gets deselected correctly from the hierarchy. But when you select it again from the hierarchy, it shows up twice in the side-view list now.

Somehow the list instance in the right-side component does not get updated when a node is selected again which has been previously deselected.

Any inputs on how to fix this? It is something similar to this plunkr I found online : http://next.plnkr.co/edit/1Fr83XHkY0bWd9IzOwuT?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=worker&utm_campaign=next&preview

Comment: How about a StackBlitz example showing your specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that you're using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and performing mutations within `onSliceChange` of the SliceComponent without an explicit call to `cd.markForCheck()`.

Either remove `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` from SliceComponent or add `cd.markForCheck()` to the end of `onSliceChange`

When you set the change detection to OnPush, Angular only guarantees that the component will be updated when the references passed to it's Inputs are changed. `onSliceChange` doesn't replace any Input, so the slice component won't be updated.

You should also consider replacing `deselect` in RightSideComponent with an Output and handling the changes in SliceComponent. The convention of one-way data flow is to only modify common state in the common parent. This prevents conflicts when two components both want to modify some shared state.

Comment: I added cd.markForCheck() at the end of onSlicechange but the behavior is still the same. The list still has ALL of the contents in it once an item is selected again which has previously been deselected. i.e order of operation - select item, delete from side list, re-select same item - It appears twice in the side list now instead of once.